# Return unique array values from an array inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I can't find a similar question and I'm a bit stuck. I have the following JSON array:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "element1",
        "Attributes": ["1", "2"]
    },

    {
        "Name": "element2",
        "Attributes": ["1","3" ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "element3",
        "Attributes": []
    }
]
```

I'm trying to create an array of all the unique elements in the "Attributes" property, but I'm having trouble looping through each object, and then looping through the array elements to return the unique values. I'm trying to do it with filter(), or map() preferably.

EDIT: I want an array of unique elements, so: [1,2,3].

Comment: please add the wanted result and the code you tried.

Comment: I'vr added my desired output, but I'm stuck with how to do a filter() within a map(), and return the output of the inside filter() back up the the containing map()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: I don't have any working code.. that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with couple of Array methods. For example:

```js
var result = [
    {
        "Name": "element1",
        "Attributes": ["1", "2"]
    },

    {
        "Name": "element2",
        "Attributes": ["1","3" ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "element3",
        "Attributes": []
    }
]

// map to [ ["1", "2"], ["1", "3"], [] ]
.map(item => item.Attributes)

// flatten to [ "1", "2", "1", "3" ]
.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.concat(curr), [])

// filter unique [ "1", "2", "3" ]
.filter((item, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(item) === i)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: There is no need to use `apply` , `return prev.concat(curr)` is enough

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** and **[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter)** methods

```js
var data = [{
    "Name": "element1",
    "Attributes": ["1", "2"]
  },

  {
    "Name": "element2",
    "Attributes": ["1", "3"]
  }, {
    "Name": "element3",
    "Attributes": []
  }
]

console.log(
  // iterate over array elements
  data.reduce(function(arr, ele) {
    // push the unique values to array
    [].push.apply(arr,
      // filter out unique value
      ele.Attributes.filter(function(v) {
        // check element present in array
        return arr.indexOf(v) == -1;
      })
    );
    // return the unique array
    return arr;
    // set initial argument as an empty array
  }, [])
);
```

---

With **[ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)**

```js
 var data = [{
     "Name": "element1",
     "Attributes": ["1", "2"]
   },

   {
     "Name": "element2",
     "Attributes": ["1", "3"]
   }, {
     "Name": "element3",
     "Attributes": []
   }
 ]

 console.log(
   data.reduce((arr, ele) => ([].push.apply(arr, ele.Attributes.filter((v) => arr.indexOf(v) == -1)), arr), [])
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

If [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) is an option, you can easily get what you want:

```
> _.chain(foo).map('Attributes').flatten().uniq().value()
["1", "2", "3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let uniqueSet = new Set()

let a = [
    {
        "Name": "element1",
        "Attributes": ["1", "2"]
    },

    {
        "Name": "element2",
        "Attributes": ["1","3" ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "element3",
        "Attributes": []
    }
]

for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    a[i].Attributes.map((x) => uniqueSet.add(x))
}

console.log([...uniqueSet])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
var uniqueArr = [];

var arr = [
    {
        "Name": "element1",
        "Attributes": ["1", "2"]
    },

    {
        "Name": "element2",
        "Attributes": ["1","3" ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "element3",
        "Attributes": []
    }
];

arr.forEach(function(obj) {
   var attr = obj.Attributes;
   attr.forEach(function(val){
       if (uniqueArray.indexOf(val) < 0) {
           uniqueArray.push(val)
       }
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have answers to choose from. Just for fun: this one uses es6

```js
"use strict";
let uniqueAttr = [];
const obj = [
    {
        "Name": "element1",
        "Attributes": ["1", "2"]
    },

    {
        "Name": "element2",
        "Attributes": ["1","3" ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "element3",
        "Attributes": []
    }
];

obj.forEach( element => 
  element.Attributes.forEach( 
    attr => uniqueAttr.indexOf(attr) < 0  && uniqueAttr.push(attr)
  ) 
);

document.querySelector("#result").textContent = uniqueAttr;
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This, It'll help to solve this problem.

```js
  var data = [{
    "Name": "element1",
    "Attributes": ["1", "2"]
  }, {
    "Name": "element2",
    "Attributes": ["1", "3"]
  }, {
    "Name": "element3",
    "Attributes": []
  }];
  var Attributes = [];
  $.each(data, function(i, e) {
    $.each(e.Attributes, function(i, e) {
      Attributes.push(parseInt(e));
    });
  });
  Attributes = $.unique(Attributes);
  alert(Attributes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6/ES2015 you can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```js
const input = [
    {
        "Name": "element1",
        "Attributes": ["1", "2"]
    },

    {
        "Name": "element2",
        "Attributes": ["1","3" ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "element3",
        "Attributes": []
    }
];

const output = [...new Set([].concat(...input.map(item => item.Attributes)))];

console.log(output);
```

Explanation (from the inside out):

- `input.map(item => item.Attributes)` produces an array of the Attributes arrays
- `[].concat(...)` flattens the arrays, i.e. produces an array of all the Attributes values (including duplicates)
- `new Set()` produces a Set from the array, i.e. stores only the unique Attribute values
- `[...]` produces an array from the Set's values, i.e. produces an array of all unique Attribute values

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of @dfsq answer, you could replace the two `map` and `reduce` with a single `flatMap`

```js
var result = [
    {
        "Name": "element1",
        "Attributes": ["1", "2"]
    },

    {
        "Name": "element2",
        "Attributes": ["1","3" ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "element3",
        "Attributes": []
    }
]

// map & flatten to [ "1", "2", "1", "3" ]
.flatMap(item => item.Attributes)

// filter unique [ "1", "2", "3" ]
.filter((item, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(item) === i)

console.log(result)
```